# Why does this equality hold (integrals)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, economics

Could someone explain the last equality for me?

[image]

Source: MWG Microeconomic Theory

Comment: The last term has no $p_1$ dependence so the integral over $p_1$ of that term is just the term itself times the length of the interval we integrate over (which is [upper bound] - [lowerbound] = $t$).

Comment: I see. But doesn't $p^0_1$ means it depends on $p_1$?

Comment: I don't know what that symbol means. But I assume it's just a constant as it's in the upper and lower integration limits.

Answer (score 1):

This follows because $c=-h_1(p_1^0 + t, \bar{p}_{-1},u^1)$ is a constant with respect to $p_1$, so when we integrate it we just get
$$\int_{a}^{a + t} c\ dx = xc\big|_a^{a+t} = (a+t)c-ac = tc$$